# Eigen3 Flatten Matrix as Vector

Tags: eigen3

In MATLAB, I can do the following

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
A(:)
```

to get:

```
ans =
1
4
2
5
3
6
```

How would I do this with an Eigen3 Matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to use Map:

```
Map<VectorXd> v(A.data(),A.size());
```

because in this case Eigen knows at compile time that you now have a 1D vector.

Of course, the result will depend on the storage order of A, that is, for a column major matrix (the default):

```
[1 4 2 5 3 6]^T
```

and for a row-major one:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]^T
```

Comment: The second suggestion is a bad idea because it assumes that A is stored internally in row-major format with no offset between rows. In the simple example above, this will always be true, but in other cases it will not be.

Comment: That's 'resize()' you want to use, 'conservativeResize()' won't work. See proper answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881768/eigen-convert-matrix-to-vector

Comment: hm, I've too fast of that one, you're right conservativeResize won't work here.