# Eigen Convert Matrix to Vector

Tags: matlab, eigen

In MATLAB, the line below converts a matrix to a vector. It flattens the matrix column by column into a vector.

```matlab
myvar(:)
```

How do I do that with Eigen? The solution should work for any dimension of matrix.

```cpp
MatrixXd A(3,2);
VectorXd B(6);
A << 1,2,3,4,5,6;
B << A.col(0), A.col(1); 
//This isn't general enough to work on any size Matrix
```

Comment: myvar(:) takes a matrix **column** wise and places it into a vector, not row-wise.

Answer (score 18):

Eigen matrices are stored in column major order by default, so you can use simply use Eigen Maps to store the data column by column in an array:

```cpp
MatrixXd A(3,2);
A << 1,2,3,4,5,6;
VectorXd B(Map<VectorXd>(A.data(), A.cols()*A.rows()));
```

If you want the data ordered row by row, you need to transpose the matrix first:

```cpp
MatrixXd A(3,2);
A << 1,2,3,4,5,6;
A.transposeInPlace();
VectorXd B(Map<VectorXd>(A.data(), A.cols()*A.rows()));
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation of Eigen itself](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReshape.html):

```
MatrixXd A;
VectorXd B = VectorXd {A.reshaped()};
```

`reshaped` produced a linear view of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna change the matrix values without defining a new variable you can use

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A(2,3);
A.data()[3] = 1.2
```

in this case data()[3] will correspond to index A[1,1] of matrix, or read them by

```
double value = A.data()[5];
```

so if I write down the whole 2by3 matrix it would be like

```
A.data()[0]     A.data()[2]    A.data()[4]
A.data()[1]     A.data()[3]    A.data()[5]
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do it is:

```
...
VectorXd B = A;
B.resize(B.cols()*B.rows(), 1);
```

or, if you want the vector in row order:

```
...
VectorXd B = A.transpose();
B.resize(B.cols()*B.rows(), 1);
```

Regards.

Comment: Assigning a 'Matrix' to a 'Vector' is bound to fail.